# Exception when trying to fetch channelId using the youtube api in objective c

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api

I am trying to fetch youtube channel id using the google-api-objectivec-client. The problem I am having is basically that for some reason I am receiving exception when trying to access the channelId. The code I am using:

```
GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
service.APIKey = _MY_API_KEY_;
GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"id"];
query.q = @"google";
query.type = @"channel";
query.maxResults = 1;
GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        GTLYouTubeSearchListResponse *products = object;
        for (id item in products.items) {
            GTLYouTubeSearchResult *result = item;
            NSLog(@"Identifier:%@",result.identifier);
            GTLYouTubeResourceId* resourceId = result.identifier;
            NSLog(@"kind:%@",resourceId.kind);
            NSLog(@"channel:%@",resourceId.channelId);
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

The output I get when i am running this code is:

```
2013-04-05 11:37:12.615 YouTest[21704:11303] Identifier:GTLYouTubeChannel 0x7233b00: {kind:"youtube#channel" channelId?:"UCK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA"}
2013-04-05 11:37:12.617 YouTest[21704:11303] kind:youtube#channel
2013-04-05 11:37:12.617 YouTest[21704:11303] -[GTLYouTubeChannel channelId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7233b00
2013-04-05 11:37:12.618 YouTest[21704:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GTLYouTubeChannel channelId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7233b00'
```

So my implementation crashes on the point where I am trying to access the channelId of the resourceId. From the documentation I understood that the channelId should be there as the type of the resourceId is youtube#channel. The channelId can be off course parsed from the result.identifier string that I am also printing, but since there is a property for the channelId I would prefer using that.

Any ideas about what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a bug in the Google libraries. However I solved this problem by accessing the JSON string directly and parsing it with the help of the NSString+SBJSON.h class, as in this example.

```
#import "NSString+SBJSON.h"

...

GTLYouTubeResourceId *resource = channel.snippet.resourceId;

NSDictionary *jsonObject = [resource.JSONString JSONValue];

NSString *channelid = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"channelId"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Objective-C, but yeah, that looks like there's something wrong with the generated client library's YouTube Data API v3 bindings. Are you using the latest version from the [project page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/)? You might want to [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/list) against the client library if you can reproduce it with the latest version. While troubleshooting this further, I'd check to see if you have the same problem when `query.type = @"video";` and you try to access the videoId of the response item.

Here's an alternative you could try, though. The channel's id is also returned in the [snippet.channelId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#snippet.channelId) property. If you request the snippet part via `GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"snippet"];` see if you can read that value instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved it with the following...

```
     NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[resourceId.JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
            NSString *channelId = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"channelId"];
            NSLog(@"channelId is %@", channelId);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround Code:

```
    channel.snippet.resourceId.JSON[@"channelId"];
```

No need to parse the JSON yourself as the underlying JSON is exposed.

It looks like the automatic binding is not working for GTLYouTubeResourceId because the "kind" element of "youtube#channel" is throwing off the runtime object creation and creating a GTLYouTubeChannel instead.

### Thorough Workaround Code:

```
ticket.surrogates = @{ (id)[GTLYouTubeChannel class] : [GTLYouTubeResourceId class] };
```

If you really want to force that binding to work you can workaround a little further upstream on the ticket when you execute the query.

### Global Workaround Patch:

https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/pull/109

There's open tickets for the issue:

https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/63

https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/92

It seems they want to change the API to not call the resourceId.kind 'kind' to avoid this problem. But while we wait for the API to change, any of these three workarounds should serve your purposes.